# Como seleccionar elementos de un Multiselect y ponerlos en otro lugar

Tags: javascript, multiselect

Colegas tengo el siguiente multiselect:

[image: Multiselec]

Pero estoy intentando programar el boton de seleccionar todo y esta es la función que me desarolle:

```
function selected_all(select_id){

    var obj = document.getElementById(select_id);

    for(var i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++){
        obj.options[i].selected = true;

    }
}
```

Esta función la probe y selecciona todos lso elementos que tiene el multiselect pero no me lo envia hacia el otro cuadro.

Que pudiera estar haciendo mal??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Colocar elementos de un `multiselect` en otro lugar

> **Nota:** las hojas de estilos definidas acá no forman parte parte de la solución. Su objetivo es ayudar a visualizar los elementos sobre los que se interactuarán para facilitar la comprensión de lo que se hace con **JavaScript**.

Estuve analizando el siguiente fragmento:

```js
function selected_all(select_id) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(select_id);
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.options.length; i++) {
    obj.options[i].selected = true;
  }
}
```

Y cumple efectivamente con seleccionar las opciones del elemento `select` de origen. Sin embargo, no se obseva que lo envía hacia un elemento HTML de destino (`select` en este caso).

Por ejemplo, solamente selecciona los elementos:

```js
obj.options[i].selected = true;
```

Pero, para enviarlo hacia el otro elemento, deberías escribir la siguiente sintaxis:

```js
elementoDestino.append( obj.options[i] );
```

El método `append( elementoHTML )` del elemento de destino es la que hace posible lo que se intenta buscar.

Sin embargo, si intenta enviar directamente el elemento desde su origen hacia su destino:

```js
seleccionar.onclick = () => {
  for (let elemento of origen)
    destino.append(elemento);
}

deseleccionar.onclick = () => {
  for (let elemento of destino)
    origen.append(elemento);
}
```

```html
<select id="origen" multiple>
  <option value="">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="">Valor 3</option>
  <option value="">Valor 4</option>
</select>

<select id="destino" multiple></select>

<hr>

<button id="seleccionar">Seleccionar Todo</button>
<button id="deseleccionar">Deseleccionar Todo</button>
```

Se observarán resultados no deseados porque cambia la longitud de la colección de elementos que recorre el bucle; pero pueden resolverse de cualquiera de las dos formas:

- Obteniendo los elementos `option` que forman parte del elemento `select` de origen mediante:

  ```js
  const elementos = document.querySelectorAll( "#origen option" );
  ```
- O almacenar en un `Array` los elementos obtenidos:

  ```js
  let elementos = [];

  for ( let option of origen )
    elementos.push( option );
  ```

Si utilizamos cualquiera de las dos formas anteriormente mencionadas obtendremos los siguientes resultados deseados:

```js
const elementos = document.querySelectorAll("#origen option");

seleccionar.onclick = () => {
  for (let elemento of elementos)
    destino.append(elemento);
}

deseleccionar.onclick = () => {
  for (let elemento of elementos)
    origen.append(elemento);
}
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<select id="origen" multiple>
  <option value="">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="">Valor 3</option>
  <option value="">Valor 4</option>
</select>

<select id="destino" multiple></select>

<hr>

<button id="seleccionar">Seleccionar Todo</button>
<button id="deseleccionar">Deseleccionar Todo</button>
```

### Realizando pruebas

Teniendo claro lo anteriormente expuesto en esta publicación desarrollaremos un ejemplo mucho más completo como propuesta, a la vez, un poco más complejo, que será documentado mediante comentarios insertados en el código.

Visualmente se verá así:

[image]

Tome en cuenta que el botón que tiene la doble flecha permite intercambiar de lugar los elementos seleccionados y los botones **Seleccionar Todo** y **Deseleccionar Todo** cambiarán de lugar todos los elementos `option` contenidos en el elemento `select`.

Antes de empezar, describamos las dos funciones que vamos a utilizar:

- **`intercambiarDestino( _origen, _destino )`:** esta función permitirá intercambiar origen y destino del elemento seleccionado por el usuario. El parámetro `_origen` es el elemento de origen, mientras que el parámetro `_destino` es el elemento de destino.
- **`origenDestino( _origen, _destino )`:** esta función permitirá enviar todos los elementos contenidos en el `select`  de origen hacia el elemento `select` de destino; donde el parámetro `_origen` es el elemento `select` de origen, mientras que `_destino` es el elemento `select` de destino.

Sin más preámbulos visualicemos el siguiente ejemplo ejecutable:

```js
// Es una función que permitirá cambiar los elementos
// seleccionados de un lugar a otro:
const intercambiarDestino = (_origen, _destino) => {
  // Se evalúa si los parámetros son válidos
  if (typeof _origen === "undefined" || _origen === null) return;
  if (typeof _destino === "undefined" || _destino === null) return;

  // Array donde se almacenrán los elementos «option» que 
  // forman parte del elemento «select»
  let elementosA = [],
    elementosB = [];

  // Almacenamos en el array «elementosA» todos los elementos
  // del primer elemento «select»:
  for (let elemento of _origen)
    // Se evalúa que previamente haya sido seleccionado:
    if (elemento.selected) {
      elemento.selected = false;
      elementosA.push(elemento);
    }

  // Almacenamos en el array «elementosB» todos los elementos
  // del segundo elemento «select»:
  for (let elemento of _destino)
    // Se evalúa que previamente haya sido seleccionado:
    if (elemento.selected) {
      elemento.selected = false;
      elementosB.push(elemento);
    }

  // Trasladamos todos los elementos enviados a «elementosA»
  // hacia el segundo «select»:
  for (let elemento of elementosA)
    _destino.append(elemento);

  // Trasladamos todos los elementos enviados a «elementosB»
  // hacia el primer «select»:
  for (let elemento of elementosB)
    _origen.append(elemento);

  // Vaciamos los arrays de todos los elementos que hayan
  // sido enviados hacia ellos:
  elementosA = [];
  elementosB = [];
};


// Esta función cambia todos los elementos de 
// un lugar a otro:
const origenDestino = (_origen, _destino) => {
  // Se evalúa que los parámetros sean válidos:
  if (typeof _origen === "undefined" || typeof _origen === "null" || typeof _destino === "undefined" || typeof _destino === "null")
    return;

  // Almacenar todas las opciones del elemento 
  // «select» de origen para intercambiarlos
  // en el elemento «select» de destino:
  let opciones = [];
  for (let opcion of _origen) {
    opciones.push(opcion);
    opcion.selected = false;
  }

  // Enviamos todos los elementos almacenados previamente en
  // el array «opciones» hacia el elemento «select» de destino:
  for (let opcion of opciones)
    _destino.append(opcion);

  // Vaciamos el array opciones de los elementos del 
  // «select» origen:
  opciones = [];
};

// Cuando el usuario presiona el botón intercambiar (que tiene
// doble flechas) puede cambiar elementos seleccionados de un 
// lugar a otro:
intercambiar.onclick = () => {
  intercambiarDestino(input, output);
};

// Mueve todos los elementos «options» hacia el otro elemento:
seleccionar.onclick = () => {
  origenDestino(input, output);
}

// Realiza la misma acción que la anterior, pero al revés:
deseleccionar.onclick = () => {
  origenDestino(output, input);
}
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css";
:root {
  --color: #0080d4;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif, arial;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

select {
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 128, 213, 0.1);
}

option {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  color: #0080d4;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

option:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 128, 213, 0.3);
}

hr {
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.botones {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba( 0, 128, 213, 0.1);
}

.botones__item {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #0080d4;
  color: white;
  height: 33px;
}

.botones__item:hover {
  background-color: #0080e2;
}

.botones__item:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.flex,
.flex__item--boton {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  /* Propiedades temporales: */
  padding: 5px;
  /* Espacio disponible para el botón de intercambio */
  --width: 50px;
}

.flex__item {
  background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  flex-basis: calc( 50% - var(--width) / 2);
}

.flex__item--boton {
  background-color: white;
  flex-basis: var(--width);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex__item">
    <label class="flex__item">
      <p>Permisos disponibles:</p>
      <select id="input" multiple>
        <option value="1">Navegar Usuarios (Lista y navega todos los usuarios del sistema)</option>
        <option value="2">Crear Usuario (sin descripción)</option>
        <option value="3">Editar Usuario (sin descripción)</option>
        <option value="4">Mostrar Usuario (sin descripción)</option>
        <option value="5">Eliminar Usuario (sin descripción)</option>
      </select>
    </label>

    <div class="botones">
      <button id="seleccionar" class="botones__item">Seleccionar Todo &nbsp;<i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex__item flex__item--boton">
    <button id="intercambiar" class="botones__item"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt fa-lg"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="flex__item">
    <label class="flex__item">
      <p>Permisos Asignados:</p>
      <select id="output" multiple></select>
    </label>

    <div class="botones">
      <button id="deseleccionar" class="botones__item"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left">&nbsp;</i>Deseleccionar Todo</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```